# Tamper Data crashing firefox

Tags: firefox, crash, firefox-addon, tamper-data

I am using Tamper Data on Firefox. When I try to make a change, my Firefox stops working, this returned to work only once.

Can you help me?

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not right place to report bugs with the Tamper Data add-on. Check [their homepage](http://tamperdata.mozdev.org/) for more appropriate options.

Comment: It's weird man, we don't know why, you'll have to email the addon author for more help.